# Join two nodes in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app, which is supposed to show data from two nodes(Firebase). Firebase DB is structured as:

```
{
    "College": {
        "4F2EAB65": {
            "id": "4F2EAB65",
            "name": "SomeCollege"
        },
        "A3C2ED31": {
            "id": "A3C2ED31",
            "name": "OtherCollege"
        },
        "F967B5A0": {
            "id": "F967B5A0",
            "name": "CoolCollege"
        }
    },
    "Student": {
        "3E20545B": {
            "college-ID": "4F2EAB65",
            "id": "3E20545B",
            "name": "A"
        },
        "6FDEE194": {
            "college-ID": "F967B5A0",
            "id": "6FDEE194",
            "name": "B"
        }
    }
```

I want to fetch student details having details: "id", "name", "college-ID", "college-Name"(Need to fetch "college-Name" by "college-ID").

I've achieved this using `for` loop at front end. Is there any way to get this achieved at Firebase server, also can we make something like join (SQL).

Thanks.

Comment: The web is full of examples and tutorials on Firebase join. This is just the first one: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html

Comment: One way to could be to implement an indexer. Firebase themselves suggest using Algolia for full text search - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for server-side joins in the Firebase Realtime Database. Client-side joins are quite normal.

The alternative is to duplicate the data upon writing, so that you don't have to read from two locations.

What's best for your application is a matter of personal preference, your comfort level with the code involved vs data duplication, and the use-cases of your app.

Client-side jons are likely not as slow as you may think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786